# How to use Configuration.Get() method properly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "OracleOptions": {
    "Login": "hr",
    "Password": "password"
  },
  "Test": "test value"
}
```

And I want to bing this settings to class:

```
public class OralceOptions
{
     public string Login { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I write this code in ConfigureServices method. But the config file doesn't  bind.
What is problem? What I do wrong?

```
var oracleOptions = Configuration.Get<OralceOptions>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in your `appsettings.json` file `OrcleOptions` is a nested property. You need to get down to that level and then you need to call `Get` method.
This should work :

```
var oracleOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(OralceOptions)).Get<OralceOptions>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind hierarchical configuration data using the options pattern

The preferred way to read related configuration values is using the options pattern. For example,
to read the following configuration values with your `OralceOptions` model:

```
"OracleOptions": {
    "Login": "hr",
    "Password": "password"
 }
```

you can just write the code below, it will call the `ConfigurationBinder.Bind` to bind the `OracleOptions` class to the `OracleOptions` section

```
var oracleOptions = new OracleOptions();
Configuration.GetSection("OracleOptions").Bind(oracleOptions);
```

`ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` binds and returns the specified type. `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` may be more convenient than using `ConfigurationBinder.Bind`. The following code shows how to use `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` with the OracleOptions class:

```
var positionOptions = Configuration.GetSection("OracleOptions").Get<OracleOptions>();
```